# WordPress posts loop resulting in ending of file and unclosed elements

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I am building a website for a friend who wants to use WordPress for a blog section. I could have just made the whole site as a custom WordPress theme, but I don't like using WordPress because it's bloated, slow, and buggy. So instead I want to add a recent posts module to the site by including the wp-load.php file from the WordPress site and using their functions.

I have made several attempts at creating the module and each method has resulted in an error.

Using a **while (have_posts())** loop resulted in a **500 Internal Server Error** so I tried using **wp_get_recent_posts(array** followed by a **foreach** statement, which doesn't result in the error but instead gets me an **"End of file seen and there were open elements."**

Here is the link to the site: [http://colinthompson.ca/drake/](http://colinthompson.ca/drake)
Here is the code for that section:

```
<section id="blog">
    <h3>recent posts</h3>
    <div id="post-wrap">
    <?php 
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
            'numberposts' => 3
        )); 

        foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
            echo '<div class="blog-post">
                <div class="post-img">'.get_the_thumbnail($post['ID']).'</div>
                <h5><a href="'.get_permalink($post['ID']).'" title="read whole article">'.$post['post_title'].'</a></h5>
                <p>by <span>'.the_author($post['ID']).'</span></p>
                <p>'.the_date(d,m,y).'</p>
                <p>'.the_excerpt($post['ID']).'</p>
                </div>';
        }
    ?>
    </div>
    <a id="full-blog" href="#" title="Check out the full blog"><div class="slide-in"><p>full blog</p></div><div class="arrow-shaft"></div><div class="arrow-head"></div><p>read more</p></a>
    <a class="next-section" href="#contact" title="Let's get in touch"><div class="slide-in"></div><div class="arrow-shaft"></div><div class="arrow-head"></div></a>
</section>
```

I tried removing the foreach statement to test for unclosed elements in the html that is being echoed, but the error persisted, resulting in the **unclosing** of the parent **div#post-wrap** and grandparent **section#blog** and general fudging of the rest of the document.

When I **removed the wp_get_recent_posts** array the page loaded as **normal**, but without the posts of course.

Maybe I did simply forget to escape something but I don't see it.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You may need to replace `$post['post_title']` with `htmlspecialchars($post['post_title']);` If that doesn't work, you should try removing the date/permalink/etc until you find the source of the issue.

Comment: Hey Maury.  As far as I can tell the problem isn't in the foreach statement. I removed the entire foreach statement and all the echoes but the problem persisted.  It's after removing the array statement that the elements close properly, so it must be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you going to display the posts? Where is your friend going to write them?

It seems to me you are much better off including WordPress in it's entirety on just one part of the site.

Comment: I am trying to add the module to a simple HTML site (http://colinthompson.ca/drake) using PHP to include the wp-load.php file of the WordPress site I set up in a directory called "blog" (http://colinthompson.ca/drake/blog).  That's so the public can see the full blog and my friend can login to create new blog posts.  I have read a few articles on how to do this, so it's obviously possible, however I may have to cave and just make the whole thing in WordPress.  Thanks for the response.